# bootstrap button coloring issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to style and color buttons in bootstrap, however when I change the color, when hovering, it comes out like this:
   **edit: I need more reputation points to post images, but what happens is when I hover over it, only half of the chosen color shows. I think it has to do with bootstrap not being able to read 'gradients.'

What's the deal? here's my code:

```
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  *margin-left: .3em;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ff0001;
  *background-color: red;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, red, #e6e6e6);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ff0001), to(#ff0001));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  *border: 0;
  border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-bottom-color: #b3b3b3;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
          border-radius: 4px;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='red', endColorstr='red', GradientType=0);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
  *zoom: 1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

Comment: What's the btn hover css? The gradient displays properly: http://jsfiddle.net/j7EJX/ there is no hover state. What browser is this an issue in?

Comment: you need to override the background color of the hover state, typically you should use the bottom color of your gradient

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's buttons have background-position applied to them:

```
.btn:hover {
background-position: 0 -15px;
-webkit-transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
-moz-transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
-o-transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
}
```

You can either delete the style in bootstrap's main css file. Or add this to your own css file:

```
.btn:hover {
background-position: 0px;
}
```